# Wordpress auto trim the_content questions

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a this function.

```
function trim_the_content( $the_contents = '', $read_more_tag = '...READ MORE', $perma_link_to = '', $all_words = 100 ) {
    // make the list of allowed tags
    $allowed_tags = array( 'a', 'abbr', 'b', 'blockquote', 'b', 'cite', 'code', 'div', 'em', 'fon', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'hr', 'i', 'label', 'i', 'p', 'pre', 'span', 'strong', 'title', 'ul', 'ol', 'li', 'object', 'embed', 'param' );
    if( $the_contents != '' && $all_words > 0 ) {
        // process allowed tags
        $allowed_tags = '<' . implode( '><', $allowed_tags ) . '>';
        $the_contents = str_replace( ' ]]>', ' ]]>', $the_contents );
        $the_contents = strip_tags( $the_contents, $allowed_tags );
        // exclude HTML from counting words
        if( $all_words > count( preg_split( '/[\s]+/', strip_tags( $the_contents ), -1 ) ) ) return $the_contents;
        // count all
        $all_chunks = preg_split( '/([\s]+)/', $the_contents, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
        $the_contents = '';
        $count_words = 0;
        $enclosed_by_tag = false;
        foreach( $all_chunks as $chunk ) {
            // is tag opened?
            if( 0 < preg_match( '/<[^>]*$/s', $chunk ) ) $enclosed_by_tag = true;
            elseif( 0 < preg_match( '/>[^<]*$/s', $chunk ) ) $enclosed_by_tag = false; 
            if( !$enclosed_by_tag && '' != trim( $chunk ) && substr( $chunk, -1, 1 ) != '>' ) $count_words ++;
            $the_contents .= $chunk;
            if( $count_words >= $all_words && !$enclosed_by_tag ) break;
        }
                // note the class named 'more-link'. style it on your own
        $the_contents = $the_contents . '' . $READ_MORE_TAG . '';
        // native WordPress check for unclosed tags
        $the_contents = force_balance_tags( $the_contents );
    }
    return $the_contents;
}
```

When I call the function in my index the "Read More..." is missing.

```
<?php
// here's the point where we are about to display Post excerpt
$perma_link = get_permalink( $post->ID ); // current Post permalink
$content = get_the_content(); // save entire content in variable
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content ); // WP bug fix
$content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]>', $content ); // ...as well
echo trim_the_content( $content, __( "READ MORE", "sofa_memento" ), $perma_link, 100 );
?>
```

Does anyone see my problem?

Comment: $READ_MORE_TAG is in caps? / $read_more_tag = '...READ MORE'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$the_contents = $the_contents . '' . $read_more_tag . '';
```

Comment: Or just: `$the_contents=$the_contents.$read_more_tag;`...no need for frivolous single quotes.

Comment: yeah obviously no need for the extra, just thought find the line quicker ;/

Comment: My comment was mostly directed to the OP, sorry if it seemed otherwise.